# Python: How do I parse and edit attribute to all the edges from gxl file to networkx

Tags: python, xml, parsing, networkx

I have GXL file with nodes and edge attributes as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gxl>
  <graph id="Network" edgeids="true" edgemode="undirected">
    <node id="_103">
      <attr name="OTU"><int>103</int></attr>
      <attr name="Bacteria"><string>Bif</string></attr>
    </node>
    :
    :
    :

<edge from="_103" to="_147">
  <attr name="nlr"><float>0.106</float></attr>
</edge>
<edge from="_103" to="_152">
  <attr name="nlr"><float>0.343</float></attr>
</edge>
    :
    :
    :
```

I have shared the Googledrive link with the working example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HO4B_yLyEOhhRMN6YlmsaHdn2vQ1s1Yw/view?usp=sharing
I parsed this file into netwrokx using ElementTree as follows:

```
tree_gxl = ET.parse("CONTROL1.gxl")
root_gxl = tree_gxl.getroot()
node_id = []
edge_attr={}
# Parse nodes
for i, node in enumerate(root_gxl.iter('node')):
    node_id += [node.get('id')]

node_id = np.array(node_id)
# Create adjacency matrix
am = np.zeros((len(node_id), len(node_id)))
##Parsing edges
for edge in root_gxl.iter('edge'):
    s = np.where(node_id==edge.get('from'))[0][0]
    t = np.where(node_id==edge.get('to'))[0][0]
# Undirected Graph
    am[s,t] = 1
    am[t,s] = 1
# Create the networkx graph
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(am)
```

I need to do the following steps: 
1. Parse edge attributes to the graph G
2. after parsing, I need to replace the values in the edge attributes 
as follows:

```
(nlr*13.54)-13.54
```

nlr will be replaced by each edge attribute

How can I proceed with this?

Comment: Can you upload a minimal working sample? Right now you are loading your graph with a .gxl file that is not fully provided.

Comment: @Kimbold. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HO4B_yLyEOhhRMN6YlmsaHdn2vQ1s1Yw/view?usp=sharing. Kindly check the working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into it and would solve it this way:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np 
import networkx as nx
import re

G=nx.Graph()

tree_gxl = ET.parse("CONTROL1.gxl")
root_gxl = tree_gxl.getroot()
node_id = []
edge_attr={}
# Parse nodes
for i, node in enumerate(root_gxl.iter('node')):
    node_id += [node.get('id')]

node_id = np.array(node_id)
# Create adjacency matrix
am = np.zeros((len(node_id), len(node_id)))
##Parsing edges
for edge in root_gxl.iter('edge'):
    s = np.where(node_id==edge.get('from'))[0][0]
    t = np.where(node_id==edge.get('to'))[0][0]

    # Get the child node of the current edge for the nrl value
    for node in edge:
      content = ET.tostring(node).decode("utf-8") 
      # Get the nrl value via regex
      r1 = re.findall(r"\d.\d+",content)       

      # Modify value according to: (nlr*13.54)-13.54       
      r1 = (float(r1[0])*13.54)-13.54

    #Add edge with original node names and nlr value to graph
    G.add_edge(node_id[s],node_id[t], nlr=r1)
```

I am not very familiar with processing xml files so I could not figure out how to retrieve the float value properly. That's why I solved it a bit more complicated by getting the child of the edge and then using a regular expression to match the float value.

I also noticed that your resulting graph has not the original node labels because you are saving it to a matrix and the naming gets lost there.

So I would suggest to use the method from NetworkX graphs instead:

```
add_edge(nodex,nodey, attribute=value)
```

You can compare the output of your code and my suggested code with `G.edges.data()`, which will return the edges with the respective attributes.

Comment: @Kimbold, Thank you for the answer. I am trying to modify the value of r1 as r1=(r1*13.54)-13.54. But why I am getting can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. How do I solve this?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot about the value modification you wanted to do. I updated the solution. You get that error, because r1 is a list consisting of one string (the float value stored as a string). So you have to get the first element of r1 and then type it as a float. That's what I did in the solution. Hope it works now for you :)